# Installing TS3 Client returns "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

Tags: 15.04, mate, raspberrypi, teamspeak

I will start with saying I am new to Linux, so please be very detailed.

I just installed Ubuntu Mate 15.04 on my Raspberry Pi 2 (I also had the same issue with Ubuntu 14.04). From other posts I have read it has to do with 64/32 bit, but I have downloaded the 32 bit version of Teamspeak from [here](http://www.teamspeak.com/downloads).

I ran the `.run` file and it produced a folder, in which it contained a `.sh` file. When that file is run by double clicking, nothing happens (no error or anything), when it is run from terminal it says `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`.

Is this an issue with my operating system, hardware, or Teamspeak?

How could I go about getting the ts3 client working?

Comment: The Pi uses ARM CPUs, not Intel or AMD, so you need a version that's built for ARM CPUs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry Pi is based on an [ARM](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) computing architecture, but Teamspeak 
is available only for x86 ("32-bit") and AMD64 ("64-bit") architecture. Each binary executable file has a flag, that describes its format and target architecture. If they mismatch the host (the machine supposed to run the executable) architecture, Linux platforms will (typically) print the error mentioned in your question.

Conclusion: You cannot install Teamspeak (Client or Server) on a Raspberry Pi or other ARM-based computers.